# If condition for adding information into a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, selenium, web-scraping, selenium-chromedriver

I'd need to create a dataframe with the following columns:

```
WEB | Country | Organisation
```

I'm extracting these information from a website: however, there are some webs which do not have any information on the website. This is causing me some issues in updating the dataframe. Unfortunately, the code can work only one website a time, otherwise a captcha appears.
Please see below the code to have an idea on the individual output:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import pandas as pd

    element=[]
    organisation=[]

    x=['stackoverflow.com'] # ['livevsfox.ca'] I would suggest to try first one, then the other one

    frame_dict={}

    
    element.append(x) # I am keeping this just because I'd like to consider a for loop in future
    
    chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
                driver=webdriver.Chrome('path')
        
    response=driver.get('website/'+x) # here x should stackoverflow.com, then the other web
    
    try:
    
        wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 30)
        driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, 1000)")
        
        try: 

            error = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"section.selection div.container h2"))) # updated after answer from another post and comment below

        except: 
            continue

        # Country
        c = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//div[text()='Company data']/../following-sibling::div/descendant::b[text()='Country']/../following-sibling::div"))).text
        country.append(c)   
        
        # Organisation
        try:
            org=wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//div[text()='Company data']/../following-sibling::div/descendant::b[text()='Organisation']/../following-sibling::div"))).text
            organisation.append(org)  
        except: 
            organisation.append("Data not available")

    except: 
      break

    driver.quit()

    frame_dict.update({'WEB': element, 'Organisation': organisation, 'Country': country}) 
    df=pd.DataFrame.from_dict(frame_dict)
```

The code should do the following:

- for `x = stackoverflow.com` (this is just an example of working url), open chrome; if there is info, then extract information on organisation and country; if there is not, add 'Missing' to the dataframe; exit chrome;
- for `x = livevsfox.ca`, open chrome; if there is info, then extract information on organisation and country; if there is not, then add 'Missing' in `Organisation` and `Country` columns; exit chrome.

The expected output would be, then:

```
WEB                      Country      Organisation
stackoverflow.com          US       Stack Exchange, Inc.
livevsfox.ca             Missing       Missing
```

`livevsfox.ca` returns, in fact, the following message:

```
Sorry, livevsfox.ca could not be found or reached (error code 404)
```

message that does not appear when I look for stackoverflow.com.
Since stackoverflow.com has Country and Organisation, I can add this info in the dataframe, but I can't do the same for livevsfox.ca .
I'm thinking a possible solution could be the following:

- check if the `h2 class` element contains the message above (`"Sorry, x could not be found or reached (error code 404)"`) : this would mean that the web has no information detected;
- if the web has no information, then add `Missing` (or `NA`, up to you) in the dataframe;
- otherwise, the web has information (Owner & Country) to be added in the dataframe.

I hope you can provide some help.

Comment: There is no div with class = 'force--h4', and that's what you are looking for in your xpath

Comment: I think it's interesting that you want to do this with python! Are you trying to get ICANN/WHOIS type information on these sites? See https://newbedev.com/check-whether-domain-is-registered

Comment: Thanks Gui Weinmann. I did not know about pythonwhois library, to be honest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found a solution to this problem.

First, I detect the `h2 class` element as follows:

```
  message = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"section.section div.container h2"))).text
```

Then, I check if `message` contains specific text; for example.

```
if 'Sorry,' in message:
```

If it does, then I append the value to my lists that I will add into the dataframe:

```
 organisation.append('Missing') 
 country.append('Missing')
```

Code:

```
try:

      message = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"section.section div.container h2"))).text
      if 'Sorry,' in message: 
                    
        organisation.append('Missing') 
        country.append('Missing')
except: 
      continue
```